# Disallow special characters except '@' in email validation formula

Tags: excel, email, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have this formula which validates the email address for Excel:

```
=AND(ISERROR(FIND(" ",[Send Report To],1)),IF(ISERROR(FIND("@",[Send Report To],2)),FALSE,AND(ISERROR(FIND("@",[Send Report To],FIND("@",[Send Report To],2)+1)),IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",[Send Report To],FIND("@",[Send Report To],2)+2)),FALSE,FIND(".",[Send Report To],FIND("@",[Send Report To],2)+2)<LEN([Send Report To])))))
```

But fails when I enter this email id: `sandy,rocks@gmail.com` or `sandy.rocks@gmail,co.uk`.

Can anyone amend the validation formula above so that it avoids the special characters like commas within the email address?

Comment: Avoid means if it has commas (,), dolor sign ($) and other special characters which is not valid for e-mail address then the formula will give out "False", otherwise "TRUE". Is my assumption is right?

Comment: that's right.Best thing would be to validate after the @ symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Please look this formula. You can add more special character in or argument. I just added "!,@,#,$,%,^" these characters.

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(",",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("$",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("!",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("%",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("^",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("#",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@",A1,SEARCH("@",A1)+1))),FALSE,TRUE)
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Hi Harun, Great that works...on office 365 column validation...You are a star.

Comment: Thanks dear. Excel is really fantastic and I enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is difficult with a built-in formula

Instead, a UDF with regex is suitable to ensure email pattern matching.

Refer answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Very well explained with details and examples. Do read that post.

Based on that answer, here is the UDF I came up with

```
Function simpleCellRegex(Myrange As Range) As Boolean
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String

    strPattern = "^[a-z][a-z0-9\._]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\.?[a-z]+$"


    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = LCase(Myrange.Value)

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = False
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        simpleCellRegex = regEx.Test(strInput)

    End If

    Set regEx = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually i need to validate a column in sharepoint online site using office 365.Fact is that the validation of the column is as same as built on formula for excel.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as per Haruns suggestion above. This works indeed

=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(",",[Send Report To])),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("$",[Send Report To])),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("!",[Send Report To])),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("%",[Send Report To])),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("^",[Send Report To])),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("#",[Send Report To])),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@",[Send Report To],SEARCH("@",[Send Report To])+1))),FALSE,TRUE)